# Can't get NLog to throw an exception or write a log (works on my machine)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, nlog

I have a .Net webapi running on my workstation (Win10, IIS 10) and everything works like a charm. However when I push it to our production box (Win7, IIS 6) NLog will neither write a log nor throw an exception. My NLog.config is here:

```xml
 <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true"
   >

  <targets async="true">
    <target
      name="logfile"
      xsi:type="File"
      layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}${message}"
      fileName="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\App_Data\webapi.log"
    />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

No matter what I set the `fileName` property to, it will not write a log on the Win7 box and does not throw an exception. I would see the exception in the Event Viewer under Windows Logs -> System, correct?

Note that I do not have administrative access to the target Win7 box but have enough elevated privileges to write files to wwwroot.

What am I missing? An exception or some type of error would be nice.

Edit: in fact it does NOT work at all on IIS10/Win10 though it does work fine when running in Visual Studio (IIS Express?). Both Visual Studio and IIS Manager are being run "as administrator". No logfile output, no exceptions, nothing in the Event Viewer. ???

Comment: Right click the nLog.config in Solution Explorer, then click `Properties` and then set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`. After this change publish to the host sever and check if it fixes the issue

Comment: @mohsin I have it set to "Copy Always", it has no effect. It does seem that the config file is not being read for some reason, no idea why not (works well in IIS on my workstation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a NLog Troubleshooting guide on https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting

> When you get no log output from NLog, this can be because of the following reasons:
>
> - NLog cannot find the configuration file. This can happen when the NLog.config file is configured with `Build Action = None` or `Copy to Output Directory = Do not copy` in Visual Studio. Set `Build Action = Content` and `"Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer` to fix this)
> - Is your configuration file valid XML?
> - Logging rules are incorrect or no rules are defined
> - Application tracing code is incorrect.
> - There is a runtime problem with the target (such as missing permissions)
> - Logs are written to a different location.

Also you could enable the internal log: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

**Update**: if your internal log isn't working, then it would be difficult to diagnose the issue.

You could enable throwing exceptions from code:

```cs
LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
LogManager.ThrowConfigExceptions = true;
```

Comment: I have been through the NLog troubleshooting guide for the last couple hours, no luck, but thanks.Works fine on Win10/IIS10. Will have to pick it back up in the morning.

Comment: see my edits above. I was able to get to work in Visual Studio but no love at all in IIS 6 or 10. Nada.

Comment: I have marked @Julian 's answer as the answer as it was helpful, though I also needed corporate IT to set/fix some folder permissions for me on the target server....